# "Bare" Eclipse Installation for Generic Projects

Tags: eclipse

Members of my team will be working on a number of plain-text files. Rather than using a normal text editor, I would like them to utilize eclipse, so we can take advantage of the plug-ins that will make life easier... such as the svn plugin.

Therefore, I would like to provide them with an installation of Eclipse where they will set up generic projects, rather than Java projects.

However, the basic Eclipse download from the website includes all the java functionality. This means that their GUI is littered with java-related functions that are not required, and I don't really want them using.

I have attempted to remove the JDT plugins / features from the installation, but at this point the generic project functions disappear too!

How can one go about removing java functionality whilst retaining generic project functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'Eclipse Platform' contains the minimal Eclipse without the JDT or PDE Tools.

Go to http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ and choose either Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 or the release candidate of Eclipse Luna 4.4.RC3 (RC4 later today). Choose the appropriate download from the 'Platform Runtime Binary' section.

Update:

You need to open the `Resource` perspective to create projects and edit files - use `Window > Open Perspective > Other... > Resource`. The resource perspective should already be open if you start with a new workspace.

Comment: This provides me with a bare-bones eclipse, but the `File -> New` menu is entirely blank, so I cannot create new generic projects. If I open a workspace with generic projects, it can read them... it just doesn't seem to be able to create them.

Comment: Open the `Resource` perspective (Window > Open Perspective > Other... > Resource). The basic File > New items will be available in that perspective.